# Invalid argument is supplied for foreach() CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

So I have followed this example to an absolute tee: http://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/build-a-shopping-cart-with-cakephp-and-jquery-part-2

But yet it gives me an error:

```
 Warning (2): Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP\Model\Cart.php, line 38]
```

Which relates to:

```
public function getCount() {
        $allProducts = $this->read();

        if (count($allProducts)<1) {
            return 0;
        }

        $count = 0;
        foreach ($allProducts as $product) {
            debug($product);
            $count=$count+$product;

        }

        return $count;
    }
```

What makes it even more infuriating is that in the first place it was working properly. Then something happened, I do not know what. It now refuses to work. My database is correct, everything is correct.

I just don't understand I have been stuck on this for so hours upon hours

---

And also, it must be related, whenever I try to access my shopping car(CartsController)t it gives me:

```
Error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS)
```

Here is a picture of everything, that line of errors abovwe is when i click on add to cart. And when I click on shopping cart, it gets me the snytax error about unexpected class

[image: Picture of problem]

Cart.php

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
App::uses('CakeSession', 'Model/Datasource');

class Cart extends AppModel {

    public $useTable = false;

    /*
     * add a product to cart
     */
    public function add($productId) {
        $allProducts = $this->read();
        if (null!=$allProducts) {
            if (array_key_exists($productId, $allProducts)) {
                $allProducts[$productId]++;
            } else {
                $allProducts[$productId] = 1;
            }
        } else {
            $allProducts[$productId] = 1;
        }

        $this->save($allProducts);
    }

    /*
     * get total count of products
     */
    public function getCount() {
        $allProducts = $this->find('all');

        if (count($allProducts)<1) {
            return 0;
        }

        $count = 0;
        foreach ($allProducts as $product) {
            $count=$count+$product;
        }

        return $count;
    }

    /*
     * save data to session
     */
    public function save($data) {
        return CakeSession::write('cart',$data);
    }

    /*
     * read cart data from session
     */
    public function read() {
        return CakeSession::read('cart');
    }
```

}

Comment: What's shown if you add `var_dump($allProducts)` right after the line with `$this->read()`?

Comment: Nothing appears on the screen at all.

Comment: Where this syntax error appears?

Comment: I have added a picture in the op of the error messages and an explantion, you may to open it a new tab to see properly.

Comment: What is on line 5 in `Cart` model?

Comment: Line 5: `class Cart extends AppModel {` and before it on line 3 `App::uses('CakeSession', 'Model/Datasource');` Nothing on line 4

Comment: @skywalker any ideas??? I'm really really stuck and this is app is due in 6 hours.

Comment: Did you perhaps update your PHP version? And what about syntax error, where does it appear? And check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21318634/disabling-e-strict-errors-in-cakephp-beanstalk) out.

Comment: update your question with CartsController.php

Comment: I did. I think oldskool has mostly solved it though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be mixing up model methods. The [read() method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-read) is meant to read a single row from your data model (usually a database table) as it requires an id, either by setting it to the model:

```
$this->id = 2;
$this->read();
```

Or by setting it as second argument:

```
$this->read(null, 2);
```

But, by the look of it, you're trying to fetch a count of all your products, which can be obtained much simpler with the [find('count') method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-count). Your model method can be as skinny as this:

```
public function getCount() {
    return $this->find('count');
}
```

Should give you the desired results.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if he sets id in controller before calling `getCount`, would read without arguments still work?

Comment: @skywalker Yes, the id is a property of the model class. So like any PHP class, once it's set anywhere in the class, read() can be called without arguments and it will read the currently set id.

Comment: Then his code should work if he had done that? Of course, getting count is easy as you pointed out in your answer.

Comment: @skywalker I haven't tested it, but it should by the look of it. Although it's a very extensive way to achieve the same as the one-liner find('count'), I would suggest using that anyway.

Comment: That seems to have worked. It no longer complains about the foreach thing but when i click add product to add a product to the cart it throws that line of code beside shopping cart in the screenshot. I don't know whether this is a problem with what I posted or something elseMy ajax to increment a counter beside shopping cart does not work either .

Comment: @Oldskool and whenever I add the `public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->loadModel('Cart');
     

    $this->set('count',$this->Cart->getCount());
}`. It throws a ton of the same errors saying array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given